# Changing window background color by theming

Tags: 12.04, unity, themes, window

I am a bit confused about this in theme tutorials, but how would I go about changing the color of windows in Unity. I mean the File, Edit, etc. Bars to a different color and other colors related to windows. Other colors, such as window backgrounds, I've managed to do, but no matter what I change,. Any help is appreciated. Using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

I use MyUnity. It lets you tweak your theme and change the colors of your bars. You can install it from Software Center. Just do a quick search.

Or from terminal: sudo apt-get install myunity

Here's a nice little tutorial on it:

[MyUnity Tutorial](http://www.ubuntututorials.com/configure-unity-ubuntu-myunity/)

Comment: Well, you see, I'm starting to develop a theme for the windows, icons, etc. I wanted everything to be included in the theme if possible. After looking at tutorials, I now know I have to edit a gtk file to do this but I cant find the one or the particular color code to edit for it to work.

Comment: I'm actually not sure how to do that. I've never attempted making a whole theme.  This may help:

[link](http://hackerspace.lifehacker.com/a-short-guide-to-customizing-ubuntu-12-04-lts-for-beg-595909239)

Comment: You may want to look into Gpick as well.