# Can we change window background to a custom image?

Tags: unity, personalization

Can we change a window background (when a folder opens) like how a dash home looks? 
A transparent, blur with crystal clear icons. I tried with CCMS, but it won't give dash home like feel.

If there is a solution, please share.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these solutions:

Using an app called MyUnity
[Changing window background color by theming](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344229/changing-window-background-color-by-theming)

Using dconf-tools
[How to change the background colour of a window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68003/how-to-change-the-background-colour-of-a-window)